# Is it possible to configure Apache to return a blank reason phrase instead of "OK" for an HTTP 200 response?

Tags: apache-2.2, http, apache2

Instead of this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

I want the server to return this to the client:

```
HTTP/1.1 200
```

Both responses are RFC-compliant. This is for doing regression testing on a broken HTTP client.

Running Apache httpd version 2.2.14.

Comment: The spec actually [requires a space after the reason-code](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-3.1.2), though the following reason-phrase can be empty. If the server isn't sending a space, then it's the server that's broken. That said, I've never heard of being able to customize this in Apache, though of course your web application can send whatever status line it wants.

Comment: @MichaelHampton there is a space in the second code line above. Also, the application I want to test is acting as a client, not a server in this case.

Comment: Ahh, so there is a space there. It's a bit difficult to notice.